# What are the %lex and /lex lines in jison?

Tags: jison

The below code snippet can be found on: http://zaach.github.io/jison/demos/calc/, and also the jison documentation page.  After reading the jison, lex, and flex documentation - I still don't fully understand the %lex and /lex syntax.  Is it specific to the jison scanner generator?  Meaning is its only function to provide the json output later shown in the documentation?  I only ask because the jison documentation doesn't explicitly explain its purpose, and the flex/lex rules don't seem to allow for such syntax.

```
/* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions. */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex

%%
\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER';
"*"                   return '*';
"/"                   return '/';
"-"                   return '-';
"+"                   return '+';
"^"                   return '^';
"("                   return '(';
")"                   return ')';
"PI"                  return 'PI';
"E"                   return 'E';
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF';

/lex
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%lex` and `/lex` markers only delimit the section of the grammar that pertain to the scanner generator. The `%lex` marker marks the start and `/lex` marks the end.

When using `bison` and `flex` you'd put the lexer's definitions (the "scanner generator" in Jison parlance) in a `.l` file and the grammar in a `.y` file. I do not think there exist a way using `bison` and `flex` (or `yacc/lex`) to combine the two files. (It has been a very long while since I've used `bison` and `flex` so it is not impossible that there's something I don't know.)

The fact is that although Jison takes inspiration from `bison` and `flex`, it is really an independent tool. So it does include features that have no equivalent in `bison` or `flex`.

Comment: It's been 9 years and Jison docs still suck.